# How to Programatically Create WPF Buttons and Pass Parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, button, parameter-passing

As the title suggests, I need to programatically create buttons in a WPF application with each button associated with an object from a collection so that the click event will use that object as a parameter.

For example:

```
public FooWindow(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach(var foo in foos)
    {
        // Button creation code goes here, using foo
        // as the parameter when the button is clicked

        button.Click += Button_Click;
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do what you need to do with the IFoo object associated
    // with the button that called this event
}
```

All solutions I've seen so far have involved using commands (which is fine but seems overly complicated for this application), use xaml tags in unusual ways, or haven't addressed the specific implementation of auto-assigning the object as the parameter that should be used when the click event is called.

I figured out a solution I'm happy with, so I'll answer my own question, but others can suggest their own solutions if they so desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution involves creating a custom button that inherits from Button that has a publicly accessible IFoo object assigned at instantiation.

```
class FooButton : Button
{
    public IFoo Foo { get; private set; }

    public FooButton(IFoo foo) : base()
    {
        Foo = foo;
    }
}
```

This custom button is then instantiated in place of the Button and the IFoo object is assigned at that time. When the button is clicked, the IFoo object can be retrieved and passed as a parameter or otherwise used as desired.

```
public FooWindow(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach(var foo in foos)
    {
        var button = new FooButton(foo);
        button.Click += Button_Click;
        // Add the button to your xaml container here
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is FooButton button)
    {
        // Do what you need to do here, using button.Foo as
        // your parameter
    }
}
```

I don't know how extensible this solution is. I am not a wpf or xaml expert. I'm sure using the command pattern gives much more flexibility and control over many things that this doesn't, but for a simple, quick way to do this, this should suffice. :)